# ps: show thread and display as ASCII "forest"

Tags: process

My favourite `ps` invocation is:

```
ps -efww ef
```

as I need to `watch` all processes (`-e`), get extended information about them (`-f`), see the environment (`e`) they operate within, wrapping lines (`-w -w`) so I don't lose any part of that, and visually group (`f`) child processes under their parents, for an at-a-glance overview.

I have "wasted" the whole morning trying to get *any* thread information to appear as well, following the same visualisation logic above. I must have tried 40 different combinations of options. (*Actually, I just checked my `.bash_history` and I have tried more!*). Combinations included swapping `f` and `-H` for forest display, for instance. Sometimes I even tried permutations to check insidious "orderings"...

None of the threading options seem to be compatible with my "monitoring screen" setup. I am talking about `H`, `-L`, `m`, `-m` and `-T`.

I am baffled. Am I doing it wrong? How are you guys doing it?

Specifically: I need to watch for processes like download managers who go funky with 30 to 80 threads all of a sudden...